# Netcat not transferring all the content on a text file

Tags: file, text, transfer, netcat

I am trying to transfer a text file from a beaglebone black to my ubuntu computer. I run the following command on my computer(which will receive the file):

```
nc -l -v -p 60000 > result.txt
```

Then I run this command on my beaglebone black to send the file to the computer

```
nc -v -q 0 192.168.7.1 60000 < result.txt
```

Then I check the received file and it appears as if the file I sent got cut halfway through(there is only about half of the contents of the text file).

Here is the file i am trying to send:

```
254 264 247 238 237 253 235 240 234 248 238 235 238 244 254 250 256 252 240 239 237 239 244 238 233 245 246 254 246 254 240 247 248
257 257 238 235 238 255 246 239 244 231 242 238 240 239 252 247 248 250 235 231 243 246 240 243 237 240 245 244 244 232 243 243 244
255 258 245 233 236 251 236 237 243 235 244 242 241 247 248 245 253 250 245 245 246 239 235 242 234 244 238 246 259 249 239 244 247
260 256 241 235 239 247 230 236 247 233 236 244 243 245 243 249 250 241 237 248 243 245 234 242 233 246 233 242 253 246 233 248 236
264 265 243 242 241 252 235 236 241 239 235 247 244 243 244 244 233 247 235 243 235 239 247 246 226 254 238 245 253 248 243 237 250
255 259 243 235 239 252 248 240 237 239 245 248 245 252 254 251 237 247 242 237 232 241 244 239 231 251 249 246 246 243 248 245 241
264 254 255 242 234 244 250 247 248 236 246 246 247 247 243 251 236 250 243 238 246 235 244 243 237 243 239 242 255 248 251 249 247
863 252 255 243 232 245 259 236 243 229 241 245 234 247 247 247 249 243 249 238 240 232 241 237 234 236 248 249 254 246 248 237 250
861 256 250 243 229 245 260 240 240 236 247 249 235 243 243 251 247 248 245 243 236 233 239 238 240 229 239 243 251 243 247 244 248
260 258 240 242 238 247 247 239 243 240 243 240 250 248 246 251 230 250 243 240 243 237 237 240 242 242 242 244 259 245 249 241 248
266 261 243 237 248 248 248 238 239 237 247 250 242 241 252 252 230 250 250 238 237 242 245 248 234 248 253 249 246 247 246 249 242
260 259 246 241 242 246 239 244 234 234 239 241 248 245 248 252 240 255 253 244 238 246 250 246 236 248 244 243 255 252 241 241 247
257 259 244 239 238 253 234 240 237 236 236 251 244 241 246 246 241 251 238 245 247 246 237 245 231 246 234 244 257 242 241 241 242
256 265 243 239 236 247 237 234 246 233 249 245 242 246 249 251 250 255 244 247 237 240 237 243 242 248 238 238 252 251 245 241 243
252 254 246 233 243 261 237 237 246 238 241 234 243 245 249 251 250 249 238 242 235 237 243 248 239 238 244 242 243 238 239 248 243
257 269 240 228 237 256 240 240 239 243 237 233 245 240 247 243 249 253 244 232 236 241 243 234 235 245 240 258 239 244 238 249 246
261 259 251 246 231 251 254 246 243 232 244 245 246 252 249 255 238 249 247 240 244 228 246 238 245 236 243 249 249 246 254 247 248
259 260 241 244 241 250 252 240 244 235 246 245 248 251 254 241 238 250 246 242 242 233 241 249 240 246 243 243 259 245 245 246 248
258 260 241 232 252 248 252 241 244 234 252 243 248 257 250 253 235 256 255 249 233 239 246 244 233 251 250 245 251 250 250 245 246
264 257 244 246 245 250 237 236 236 233 237 247 251 249 250 245 235 255 238 249 244 250 249 247 238 254 240 240 261 245 242 247 247
255 257 243 235 236 245 235 240 240 233 253 251 250 249 249 247 253 249 238 247 245 241 238 248 233 250 243 239 259 248 246 248 244
263 263 248 240 251 248 237 235 241 234 250 243 245 243 253 246 253 254 248 248 239 240 240 240 247 247 241 250 248 253 246 248 249
254 264 249 241 237 243 237 243 243 251 234 236 245 247 246 246 256 253 242 239 242 243 242 240 243 245 245 244 247 246 242 240 250
261 257 242 232 242 253 239 243 231 247 240 234 252 243 251 244 250 259 236 238 245 244 237 239 235 242 246 249 250 242 238 249 244
258 261 241 233 240 247 240 239 234 239 239 234 244 241 250 252 257 249 243 243 247 240 238 242 239 246 243 250 252 245 246 250 252
255 257 243 237 241 240 238 239 244 251 241 232 243 248 249 252 256 260 240 243 238 240 237 244 233 245 247 243 249 252 243 242 251
258 267 244 237 237 251 239 244 247 233 251 243 249 246 249 247 252 251 250 241 245 243 243 253 250 236 239 252 250 253 255 251 248
262 257 246 235 237 252 233 235 246 242 250 251 246 244 252 250 243 247 239 252 248 244 245 249 232 247 234 247 257 249 240 242 245
257 257 246 242 240 252 244 235 248 238 243 245 243 245 248 249 252 255 243 247 249 247 248 253 231 246 244 248 253 250 239 248 250
256 262 246 234 251 255 249 241 240 235 244 247 249 250 250 259 234 255 248 251 238 237 248 242 239 251 251 242 247 248 252 243 243
263 260 243 246 238 249 247 246 251 239 246 249 244 251 255 254 236 252 248 246 245 242 242 242 244 250 244 243 260 251 245 245 250
264 264 258 248 236 250 255 240 243 232 240 250 251 252 252 259 239 248 248 241 248 234 243 237 238 236 245 244 254 244 254 249 248
261 259 240 232 229 252 235 245 238 250 244 238 244 247 256 255 257 246 239 239 239 241 244 244 244 245 244 249 251 249 241 246 251
250 266 250 248 242 242 240 242 244 247 242 238 249 253 254 251 258 259 247 243 241 242 239 242 239 245 250 242 247 246 255 242 247
259 263 254 245 244 259 241 250 245 236 247 244 249 243 250 250 261 254 245 242 241 243 245 251 240 242 244 247 252 250 242 250 250
262 252 243 239 239 256 237 244 241 228 250 244 247 248 241 243 255 248 237 246 248 236 243 248 229 244 239 249 264 252 244 250 235
255 260 246 240 245 256 235 236 245 229 243 246 248 240 245 249 256 250 240 241 249 253 248 242 242 243 249 248 251 252 238 247 244
257 254 240 242 250 250 244 236 242 240 243 241 243 242 245 249 234 247 245 245 245 243 246 237 239 244 241 249 248 247 233 244 246
258 260 242 246 241 253 250 241 250 247 241 250 245 248 250 258 246 254 248 239 240 236 242 242 244 245 246 245 252 250 242 247 249
265 263 257 247 237 245 259 248 245 240 246 248 245 249 245 249 240 247 254 245 239 234 246 253 240 241 245 250 254 244 254 253 251
265 261 255 246 233 250 253 242 239 244 246 248 242 251 242 247 229 250 243 244 248 231 247 245 239 241 239 234 252 247 247 244 244
258 254 240 244 235 252 248 239 243 235 244 250 243 255 258 256 236 253 248 236 247 236 245 241 242 251 244 246 251 249 244 241 249
258 265 243 242 246 254 254 239 240 239 245 238 244 251 244 247 235 247 246 251 234 244 247 246 239 254 240 238 256 246 248 246 247
255 255 251 241 235 247 235 240 247 235 239 244 249 242 247 255 250 259 250 248 246 244 248 251 240 247 246 248 255 248 242 244 246
255 264 250 238 238 256 239 241 243 236 248 246 249 250 249 244 253 261 245 251 245 241 240 243 234 245 241 244 261 247 241 246 247
260 268 245 239 238 251 243 242 250 239 244 239 249 246 254 247 252 252 243 242 243 241 242 248 243 246 240 246 254 250 247 241 242
257 255 245 234 239 244 235 245 236 247 244 235 246 245 242 254 252 255 241 244 237 242 240 247 236 243 252 247 249 251 244 248 248
257 252 239 234 241 257 241 244 237 245 246 235 240 244 250 244 251 250 233 243 241 240 241 238 233 245 245 256 248 254 245 247 249
265 259 244 235 253 262 243 240 238 244 247 238 251 250 253 253 247 250 241 238 232 247 245 236 235 248 245 252 246 251 247 243 249
254 260 246 232 237 246 240 243 243 242 242 241 246 249 249 247 253 258 245 244 240 241 240 239 233 241 248 248 245 246 247 245 247
```

And here is what I receive:

```
    254 264 247 238 237 253 235 240 234 248 238 235 238 244 254 250 256 252 240 239 237 239 244 238 233 245 246 254 246 254 240 247 248
257 257 238 235 238 255 246 239 244 231 242 238 240 239 252 247 248 250 235 231 243 246 240 243 237 240 245 244 244 232 243 243 244
255 258 245 233 236 251 236 237 243 235 244 242 241 247 248 245 253 250 245 245 246 239 235 242 234 244 238 246 259 249 239 244 247
260 256 241 235 239 247 230 236 247 233 236 244 243 245 243 249 250 241 237 248 243 245 234 242 233 246 233 242 253 246 233 248 236
264 265 243 242 241 252 235 236 241 239 235 247 244 243 244 244 233 247 235 243 235 239 247 246 226 254 238 245 253 248 243 237 250
255 259 243 235 239 252 248 240 237 239 245 248 245 252 254 251 237 247 242 237 232 241 244 239 231 251 249 246 246 243 248 245 241
264 254 255 242 234 244 250 247 248 236 246 246 247 247 243 251 236 250 243 238 246 235 244 243 237 243 239 242 255 248 251 249 247
863 252 255 243 232 245 259 236 243 229 241 245 234 247 247 247 249 243 249 238 240 232 241 237 234 236 248 249 254 246 248 237 250
861 256 250 243 229 245 260 240 240 236 247 249 235 243 243 251 247 248 245 243 236 233 239 238 240 229 239 243 251 243 247 244 248
260 258 240 242 238 247 247 239 243 240 243 240 250 248 246 251 230 250 243 240 243 237 237 240 242 242 242 244 259 245 249 241 248
266 261 243 237 248 248 248 238 239 237 247 250 242 241 252 252 230 250 250 238 237 242 245 248 234 248 253 249 246 247 246 249 242
260 259 246 241 242 246 239 244 234 234 239 241 248 245 248 252 240 255 253 244 238 246 250 246 236 248 244 243 255 252 241 241 247
257 259 244 239 238 253 234 240 237 236 236 251 244 241 246 246 241 251 238 245 247 246 237 245 231 246 234 244 257 242 241 241 242
256 265 243 239 236 247 237 234 246 233 249 245 242 246 249 251 250 255 244 247 237 240 237 243 242 248 238 238 252 251 245 241 243
252 254 246 233 243 261 237 237 246 238 241 234 243 245 249 251 250 249 238 242 235 237 243 248 239 238 244 242 243 238 239 248 243
257 269 240 228 237 256 240 240 239 243 237 233 245 240 247 243 249 253 244 232 236 241 243 234 235 245 240 258 239 244 238 249 246
261 259 251 246 231 251 254 246 243 232 244 245 246 252 249 255 238 249 247 240 244 228 246 238 245 236 243 249 249 246 254 247 248
259 260 241 244 241 250 252 240 244 235 246 245 248 251 254 241 238 250 246 242 242 233 241 249 240 246 243 243 259 245 245 246 248
258 260 241 232 252 248 252 241 244 234 252 243 248 257 250 253 235 256 255 249 233 239 246 244 233 251 250 245 251 250 250 245 246
264 257 244 246 245 250 237 236 236 233 237 247 251 249 250 245 235 255 238 249 244 250 249 247 238 254 240 240 261 245 242 247 247
255 257 243 235 236 245 235 240 240 233 253 251 250 249 249 247 253 249 238 247 245 241 238 248 233 250 243 239 259 248 246 248 244
263 263 248 240 251 248 237 235 241 234 250 243 245 243 253 246 253 254 248 248 239 240 240 240 247 247 241 250 248 253 246 248 249
254 264 249 241 237 243 237 243 243 251 234 236 245 247 246 246 256 253 242 239 242 243 242 240 243 245 245 244 247 246 242 240 250
261 257 242 232 242 253 239 243 231 247 240 234 252 243 251 244 250 259 236 238 245 244 237 239 235 242 246 249 250 242 238 249 244
258 261 241 233 240 247 240 239 234 239 239 234 244 241 250 252 257 249 243 243 247 240 238 242 239 246 243 250 252 245 246 250 252
255 257 243 237 241 240 238 239 244 251 241 232 243 248 249 252 256 260 240 243 238 240 237 244 233 245 247 243 249 252 243 242 251
258 267 244 237 237 251 239 244 247 233 251 243 249 246 249 247 252 251 250 241 245 243 243 253 250 236 239 252 250 253 255 251 248
262 257 246 235 237 252 233 235 246 242 250 251 246 244 252 250 243 247 239 252 248 244 245 249 232 247 234 247 257 249 240 242 245
257 257 246 242 240 252 244 235 248 238 243 245 243 245 248 249 252 255 243 247 249 247 248 253 231 246 244 248 253 250 239 248 250
256 262 246 234 251 255 249 241 240 235 244 247 249 250 250 259 234 255 248 251 238 237 248 242 239 251 251 242 247 248 252 243 243
263 260 243 246 238 249 247 246 251 239 246 249 244 251 255 254 236 252 248 246 245 242 242 242 244 250 244 243 260 251 245 245 250
264
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the wait time (`-q` on my version of `nc`). This solved some partial transfer issues for me. I used 1 second but you could try increase it if you still have issues with 1 second.

The following are the commands I use for file transfer on Ubuntu machines. Note that `nc` on different platforms has different option characters.

```
# to receive
nc -q 1 -l -p 54321 > result.txt

# to send
nc -q 1 10.0.1.110 54321 < result.txt
```

To see transfer speed, etc, you can use the `pipeviewer` application. The following example will tar the current directory and pipe it to the listener. `pv -r` will show the transfer rate through the pipe.

```
# to receive
nc -q 1 -l -p 54321 | pv -r | tar xv

# to send
tar cv . | nc -q 1 10.0.1.110 54321
```